# cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, github

Visual Studio から GitHub にプッシュしようとすると以下のエラーになります。
（文字化けは原文ママ）

```
リモート リポジトリへのプッシュ中にエラーが発生しました: Git failed with a fatal error.
HttpRequestException encountered.
   ���̗v���̑��M���ɃG���[���������܂����B
cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

SourceTreeからは問題なくプッシュできるのですが、どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017の場合はバグで、バージョン15.5.7で修正されています。
https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/949

Comment: Visual Studio 2017です。バージョン15.5.7にアップデートすると解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは。

私も同じ症状がでて、
https://github.com/settings/tokens にてアクセストークンを生成して、
`~/.gitconfig` に以下のように追記をすることで解決いたしました。

```
[url "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:x-oauth-basic@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

参考サイト
[プライベートリポジトリをgo getする方法](http://jnst.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/10/17/210612)